Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `SearchBar`
 {divisVisible && (
      <div className="absolute bg-[#ffffff] text-gray-700 w-[300px] h-auto py-3 px-3 rounded-lg mt-2 z-20 border-black border-2 border-solid ">
        {data && data.length > 0 ? (
          data?.map((item: any) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div
                  className="py-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#0000ffbe] hover:text-white hover:rounded-lg px-2"
                  key={item._id}>
                  <div
                    onClick={() => {
                      router.push(`/allproducts/${item._id}`);
                      setInput("");
                    }}>
                    {item.title}
                  </div>
                  {/* </Link> */}
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <>
            {" "}
            <div className="py-1 cursor-pointer  px-2">
              No result found...
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    )}

I tried adding keys to the rendered div but still the problem persists. This is working perfectly otherwise. Just the error keeps coming.

The child elements of your list are the fragment (<>   </>), not the div.
In your code the fragment is not necessary, so removing it should resolves the error, as you already use keys in <div key= ...>.
In case the fragment is required, see the answers in the following thread for setting a key for a fragment in react:
Can I add a key prop to a React fragment?

@fullstack-purbayan If an answer to your question solves your problem, then please accept it and vote up when you earn the privilege.
